# $L^2$ on unit circle

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I have a (presumably) very basic question concerning notation. I understand that any periodic function can be considered as a function on the unit circle $S^1$. I often read that a certain PDE holds on the circle (e.g. here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.00955.pdf )
Given this context, what is then the precise definition of $L^2(S^1)$? Are these just the measurable periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the $L^2$-norm on some intervall $[-L,L]$ ($L$ being the length of the period of the fct.) is finite?
I also don't really get how integrals of the form 
$ \int_{S^1} u(x) dx$ are defined in the context of the mentioned paper above. 
I am not really used to this $S^1$-notation.
Can someone help?

Comment: That is a long paper. You should give page and paragraph location of your specific problem. Your $L^2$ norm will be defined on 0 to $2\pi$ too but otherwise is ok.

Comment: For example in Definition 1 on page 5: There the authors mention the space $L^2(S^1)$. Of what functions does $L^2(S^1)$ consist? And what precisely does the integral (see question above) mean?

Comment: This is the space of (Lebesgue measurable) square integrable functions on the unit circle. Also $\int_{S^1} u(x) dx$ is simply an integral from 0 to $2\pi$ of u in the normal way.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_{S^1} u(x) dx = \int_0^{2\pi} u(e^{ix}) dx$? Like this?

Comment: Simpler, $\int_{S^1} u(x) dx = \int_0^{2\pi} u(x) dx$ will do. It is written as an integral over $S_1$ so that the parametrization in the integral is not fixed un-necessarily